# IE 7/8 absolute positioned elements cant go down past a certain point JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

The script is pretty simple

```
var myMenu = null;
var myItems = null;
var myTopBar = null;
var lastPos = 0;
function menuFloat()
{
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (lastPos != scrollTop)
    {    
        alert(scrollTop);
        myMenu.animate({top: scrollTop}, "slow");
    }
    lastPos = scrollTop;
    setTimeout(menuFloat, 150);
};
```

The problem is, I deal with long pages. Once the scrollTop hits about 1,300,000px my menu stops scrolling with the page. It is as if it has hit a maximum position value and it sticks.

This is Using IE8 (and 7) in Quirks and compatibility mode (has to be this way, standards mode renders too slowly for large pages like this).

Any tips for keeping my menu scrolling? (does not occur in sane browsers).

Comment: Try `position: fixed` so it's relative to the browser window instead of the document?

Comment: Can't. IE in quirks mode doesn't support position: fixed.

Comment: This is an edge case, so good luck to you, but I would like to say that there HAS to be a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski I'm all ears if you know of something. I'm displaying log files which can be in the order of millions of lines long. I was pretty surprised to see that Quirks mode in IE was so much faster than standards mode (just displaying the lines and nothing more).

Answer (score 0):

Use the registry entry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/FeatureControl/FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION
```

Add the following key:

```
iexplore.exe
```

Comment: Interesting, but registry hacks would not have helped me.  The whole problem I was running into was the fact that my clients refused to use anything other than IE7. Even IE8 was fast enough.